# Remove img default styling from certain areas

Tags: css

I recently did a styling change to my img tag and gave it a thick border but the problem is that now it's appearing on the logo and on the slider too.
Is there anyway to not let them get the same styling? a div or a class maybe? I'm sorry, I'm a newbie.

[image: http://prntscr.com/7bdxw8]

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate class and put `border:none;` inside it. Now assign this class to those images that don't need to have a border.

Problem Solved !!!

Comment: Can you tell me where should I change the logo's class and slider's image class? 
This is what in header.php i tried used span4, #logo but didn't worked.
http://prntscr.com/7bef3z

Comment: You can do it like this  `<img src="logo.jpg" class="noborder">`  and apply border to all other images like this `.img{ border:2px solid red;}` etc

Comment: I'm having last problem now. http://www.freedomgolf.com.au/ I can't seem to edit the slider's padding. I tried giving it a class in meta slider options and removing padding, border etc but no luck. Any help? Thanks!!

Comment: Have you found out from where that thick line is appearing? You need to target that element, div or whatever. What i can guess without looking at the code is, you are targeting the wrong element.

Comment: That thick line is intentional, that's box-shadow and border. :(

Comment: I would say the same thing. Play around, you must be targeting wrong element. That's why it is not showing any result.

Comment: Thanks. Been playing around but no luck thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it. Thanks for the effort, Yourfriend.

For other people :)

```
div#curve>img {
  border: 0px solid #999;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px #E5E4E2;
}
```